Ryanair check in for other person
I bought two Ryanair tickets for a friend that will come and visit me (as a birthday present). I bought them with my account but made sure to list her name as passenger. So far so good, but I realized that since they are tied to my account she probably can't use the Ryanair app. I mean I could check her in 48h before the flight and send her the PDF but she probably will have difficulty printing it. So here are my questions:

Can you add a ryanair ticket to the App of somebody else
I've read that if I add a seat selection to the ticket, I will be able to do the check-in up to 60 days earlier. So I could just print it and mail it early enough. I think if this is possible this is the way to go. Much less stress and I don't mind spending a few extra bucks to make the trip as hassle free as possible for her.
Are there any other problems that can stem from me having booked the ticket for her. Again I added her name as passenger.
She is a non Eu-citizen (Brazilian) but the flight is Schengen to Schengen (Portugal to Germany). This shouldn't be an issue, right?


Not posting as an answer because I’m not 100% sure, but AFAIK you can check in all passengers on one phone, but then anyone else can download the app and bring up the boarding pass on their own phone by entering the reservation details.
You can take a screenshot of the boarding pass then whatsapp/email/message the image to the passenger and they can use that.

For the last point (which should be a separate question, really), Ryanair have a tendency to check paperwork even when they don’t need to, and to get it wrong if you are not in the most standard cases. However since Brazilians have visa-free entry in Schengen this shouldn’t be an issue.

@jcaron She will actually fly to portugal via frankfurt so her passport will be stamped by german police come to think of it. So I doubt ryainair will make any troubles.

Anyone who knows the six-character reservation number and the associated email address (regardless of whether it's their own email address) can add the reservation to their app and check in. So you can't add it to their app, but they can.

Are there any other problems that can stem from me having booked the ticket for her. Again I added her name as passenger.

No. Ryanair don't really care who booked the ticket. The name and other details will be checked against the person's passport.

She is a non Eu-citizen (Brazilian) but the flight is Schengen to Schengen (Portugal to Germany). This shouldn't be an issue, right?

Ryanair may want to check the person's visa before they go through security. If so, the app will clearly indicate this. It looks like Brazilian citizens can do this through the app, without printing out a boarding pass.

Brazilians don’t need a visa to visit the Schengen Area.

@jcaron Lots of us don’t. But Ryanair checks all non-EU/EEA passengers.

But they won’t check for a visa. A valid passport is enough.

@jcaron I really don’t see what you’re getting at here. Ryanair checks documentation for all non-EU/EEA passengers, a procedure it refers to as a “Visa check”. My power to change that is limited.

From the page you linked to "Citizens of any of the countries listed below may complete passport verification during the check-in process via our app instead of at the visa check desk." It's actually the reason it can be done this way: there's no visa!

cool, I’ll keep that in mind. Thanks.
